# how do I solve the ConstraintViolationException in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I wrote a custom validation in spring boot. The custom validation is meant to check if two fields match. Everything works fine until i try to submit the form. Boom i experience the error:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.joker.SampleAuthenticationWebApp.model.User] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Passwords do not match!', propertyPath=con_password, rootBeanClass=class com.joker.SampleAuthenticationWebApp.model.User, messageTemplate='Passwords do not match!'}
]
```

This problem has really hindered my learning progress. Your help would be very much appreciated.
**PS: I've Scraped SO in search of a solution but all was to no avail.**
The Annotation:

```
package com.joker.SampleAuthenticationWebApp.validator;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = FieldsValueMatchValidator.class)
public @interface FieldsValueMatch {
    String message() default "Fields values don't match!";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    String field();

    String fieldMatch();

    @Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @interface List {
        FieldsValueMatch[] value();
    }
}
```

The Validator:

```
package com.joker.SampleAuthenticationWebApp.validator;

import com.joker.SampleAuthenticationWebApp.model.User;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class FieldsValueMatchValidator implements ConstraintValidator<FieldsValueMatch, Object> {
    private String field;
    private String fieldMatch;

    @Override
    public void initialize(FieldsValueMatch constraintAnnotation) {
        this.field = constraintAnnotation.field();
        this.fieldMatch = constraintAnnotation.fieldMatch();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        try {
            final Object fieldValue = new BeanWrapperImpl(value).getPropertyValue(field);
            final Object fieldMatchValue = new BeanWrapperImpl(value).getPropertyValue(fieldMatch);

            boolean isValid = fieldValue == null && fieldMatchValue == null || fieldValue != null && fieldValue.equals(fieldMatchValue);

            if (!isValid) {
                context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
                context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(context.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate()).addPropertyNode(fieldMatch).addConstraintViolation();
                return false;
            }
            return isValid;
        }
        catch (final Exception ignore) {
            // ignore
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The User Model:

```
package com.joker.SampleAuthenticationWebApp.model;

import com.joker.SampleAuthenticationWebApp.validator.FieldsValueMatch;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "auth_user")
@FieldsValueMatch(field = "password", fieldMatch = "con_password", message = "Passwords do not match!")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "native")
    @Column(name = "auth_user_id", unique = true)
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty(message = "First name is compulsory")
    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty(message = "Last name is compulsory")
    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty(message = "Email is compulsory")
    @Email
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty(message = "Password is compulsory")
    @Length(min = 5, message = "Password length should be at least 5 characters")
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Confirm Password field is compulsory")
    @Transient
    private String con_password;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private int enabled;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "auth_user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "auth_user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "auth_role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getCon_password() {
        return con_password;
    }

    public void setCon_password(String con_password) {
        this.con_password = con_password;
    }

    public int getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(int enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what you get when you use entities as form objects. When a user registers there is both a password and `con_password`. Further updates to the `User` don't have this. The easy solution is to use dedicated form objects for registration, updating etc. or start using validation groups and enable certain valiations only when certain groups are needed.

Comment: How do i setup this validation groups you talked about. I am still new to springboot and do not really know my way around. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: That has nothing to do with Spring Boot but rather how javax.validation works (or better the standard Java Validation API).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem too . The only way to solve this is to include the annotations of @ModelAttribute and @Valid on your controller class for the bean you want to check weather the condition of **@FieldsValueMatch(field = "password", fieldMatch = "con_password", message = "Passwords do not match!")** is true , after that include the BindingResult right after the bean you want to check . Check if BindigResult hasErrors(), and return what is your next step .

*EX:*

**@PostMapping("/signup")


public String signup(@ModelAttribute(name = "user") @Valid User user,BindingResult result,Model model)


if (result.hasErrors())


return "signup_form";**

Hope this is clear .